# While loop creating

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am writing a program in Python that defines a function that takes a single argument. The function has to be a while loop the returns the largest power of 16 that it is equal to. However, I am not sure how to write the while loop.

Comment: you would just type `while` followed by the expression. (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm)

Comment: Have you tried anything, where is your source code?

Comment: c'mon thats just lazy! It's easier to do a [google search](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=python+while+loop) than it is to submit a question here.

Answer (score 1):

> ### [Python Docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop)
>
> ```
> while True:
>     n = input("Please enter 'hello':")
>     if n.strip() == 'hello':
>         break
> ```

so, in layman's terms

```
while <condition>:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't completely understand your question but here's how to do a while loop to get the x to the 16th power of an input:

```
def loop_function(x):
    y = 1
    start = x
    while y != 16:
        result = start * x
        start = result
        y += 1
    return result

print loop_function(3)
```

The above code will return the answer to 3^16 which is 43046721

You can even make this a broader function two arguements

```
def loop_function(x, y):
    z = 1
    start = x
    while z != z:
        result = start * x
        start = result
        z += 1
    return result

print loop_function(3, 2)
```

The above code will return 9 i.e 3^2