# How to find the largest power of 16

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

If I have an integer number n. How can I find the largest power of 16 that is equal to, or less than, your number using a while loop? For for example, if the function was called with the value 278, it would return 256, and if it was called with 25, it would return 16.

Comment: Sounds like homework and more of a math question.

Comment: Can you please send some code you already tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While loop creating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35472493/while-loop-creating)

Answer (score 0):

provided python syntax because it was tagged with python-3.x

```
input = 278
y = 0
while( True ):
    if 16 ** (y + 1) <= input:
        y = y+1
    else:
        break

print "Output: " + str( 16 ** y )
```